# How to add item from a list to a dictionary in Python,

Tags: python, dictionary

```
itmeslist = {}
Itmesdict = {"data":[]}
fruits = ['Mango.ok', 'Grapes.ok', 'Bananna', 'Kiwi.ok', 'Oranges']
for x in fruits:
    if x.endswith(".ok"):
        itmeslist["Name"] = x
        itmeslist["Status"] = "OK"
        Itmesdict["data"].append(itmeslist)
print(Itmesdict)
```

I am trying to add items(key, value  pairs)  to a dictionary but it is adding the same item( last item ) only.
Code is Above:

Here is the Output:

```
{'data': [{'Name': 'Kiwi.ok', 'Status': 'OK'}, {'Name': 'Kiwi.ok', 'Status': 'OK'}, {'Name': 'Kiwi.ok', 'Status': 'OK'}]}
```

What I want is:

```
{'data': [{'Name': 'Mango.ok', 'Status': 'OK'}, {'Name': 'Grapes.ok', 'Status': 'OK'}, {'Name': 'Kiwi.ok', 'Status': 'OK'}]}
```

What is the issue in the code !!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to change the code a bit to keep the name and status in separate dict and then add that as a list item of main dict.

```
itmeslist = {}
Itmesdict = {"data":[]}
fruits = ['Mango.ok', 'Grapes.ok', 'Bananna', 'Kiwi.ok', 'Oranges']

for x in fruits:
    if x.endswith(".ok"):
        item = dict()
        item["Name"] = x
        item["Status"] = "OK"
        Itmesdict["data"].append(item)
print(Itmesdict)

{'data': [{'Name': 'Mango.ok', 'Status': 'OK'}, {'Name': 'Grapes.ok', 'Status': 'OK'}, {'Name': 'Kiwi.ok', 'Status': 'OK'}]}
```

You can use a one-liner like this as well,

```
Itmesdict = {"data": list(
    {"Name": fruit, "Status": "OK"} for fruit in fruits if fruit.endswith(".ok")
)}

print(Itmesdict)

{'data': [{'Name': 'Mango.ok', 'Status': 'OK'}, {'Name': 'Grapes.ok', 'Status': 'OK'}, {'Name': 'Kiwi.ok', 'Status': 'OK'}]}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should do something like this:

```py
Itmesdict = {"data":[]}
fruits = ['Mango.ok', 'Grapes.ok', 'Bananna', 'Kiwi.ok', 'Oranges']
for x in fruits:
    if x.endswith(".ok"):
        Itmesdict["data"].append({"name": x, "status": "OK"})
print(Itmesdict)
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, list are keeping the reference to the objects, not the object themselves, so you were updating the same `dict` each time. That's is why it is all `Kiwi.ok` in your output. Instead, append a copy:

```
itmeslist = {}
Itmesdict = {"data":[]}
fruits = ['Mango.ok', 'Grapes.ok', 'Bananna', 'Kiwi.ok', 'Oranges']
for x in fruits:
    if x.endswith(".ok"):
        itmeslist["Name"] = x
        itmeslist["Status"] = "OK"
        Itmesdict["data"].append(itmeslist.copy())

print(Itmesdict)
{'data': [{'Name': 'Mango.ok', 'Status': 'OK'}, {'Name': 'Grapes.ok', 'Status': 'OK'}, {'Name': 'Kiwi.ok', 'Status': 'OK'}]}
```

Answer (score 0):

@sam-sam well done, actually all works, keep good work up! :)

first at all - why You store "ok" state in string?

Maybe use the dicts? :)

some_dict = {"item_name": {"parameter": "value", ...}, ...}

Then some_dict["item_name"]["ok"] = True would be easier, dont You think?

Have You used ipdb/any other debugger (i.e. from GUI IDE) to work with Your code? It is time to learn it.

Other thing is to prepare data first as a list and then adding it :)

`itmeslist = {}` is items**dict** not list.

Try to conquer futher on Your way, and then return with futher questions in comment to this answer. Thanks :))

**EDIT:**
You should not copy itemslist **dict** EACH FOR-LOOP because it is strong antipattern, which was suggested on other answer:

```
for x in fruits:
    if x.endswith(".ok"):
        itmeslist["Name"] = x
        itmeslist["Status"] = "OK"
        Itmesdict["data"].append(itmeslist.copy())
```

Best right away answer is one from @román-cárdenas ;) but that is not teaching You :)

Answer (score 0):

```
Itmesdict = {"data":[]}
fruits = ['Mango.ok', 'Grapes.ok', 'Bananna', 'Kiwi.ok', 'Oranges']
for x in fruits:
    if x.endswith(".ok"):
        fruit = {
            'Name': x,
            'Status': 'OK'
        }

        Itmesdict["data"].append(fruit)
print(Itmesdict)
```

This will result in:

```
{'data': [{'Name': 'Mango.ok', 'Status': 'OK'}, {'Name': 'Grapes.ok', 'Status': 'OK'}, {'Name': 'Kiwi.ok', 'Status': 'OK'}]}
```